# Linq select self reference during creation in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Basically what I want is the same that is answered here but in C#:
[Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

What I have is this code:

```
private List<myObject> myFunction()
{
    return myList.Select(l => new myObject
    {
        propA = 6,
        propB = 3,
        propC = propA + propB
    }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Of course it does not work, because I cannot reference propA and propB this way. What it the right way to do it?

Thank you

Comment: You can consider to make `propC` calculable: i.e. declare it as `public int propC => propA + propB;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use body in lambda expression:

```
private List<myObject> myFunction()
{
    return myList.Select(l => 
    {
        var myObject = new myObject
        {
            propA = 6,
            propB = 3        
        };

        myObject.propC = myObject.propA + myObject.propB;

        return myObject;

    }).ToList();
}
```

Or you can return sum in getter of `propC`:

```
public int propC 
{
    get
    {
        return propA + propB;
    }
}
```

And you don't need to set `propC`.

Comment: You are missing `return myObject;`

Answer (score 3):

If you're not working with Linq to objects, (i.e. the lambdas are required to be expressions, not method delegates as with Linq to SQL/Entity Framework) you could do this with the help of an anonymous object and two Select statements:

```
return myList
    .Select(l => new {
        propA = 6,
        propB = 3})
    .Select(x => new myObject{
        propA = x.propA,
        propB = x.propB,
        propC = x.propA + x.propB
    })
    .ToList();
```